# Mocha test verify solidity contract balance

Tags: mocha.js, solidity

I have solidity contract like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Lottery {

    address public manager;

    address[] public players;

    function Lottery() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(block.difficulty, now, players));
    }

    function pickWinner() public restricted {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        players[index].transfer(this.balance);
        players = new address[](0);
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns (address[]) {
        return players;
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
      return this.balance;
    }

}
```

I am trying to test that after picking a winner that the balance/pot is back to zero.
This is the `it` statement in my test file:

```
  it('sends money to the winner and resets the players array', async() => {
    await lottery.methods.enter().send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: web3.utils.toWei('2', 'ether')
    });

    const initialBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
    await lottery.methods.pickWinner().send({ from: accounts[0] });
    const finalBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
    const difference = finalBalance - initialBalance;
    const players = await lottery.methods.getPlayers().call({
          from: accounts[0]
    });
    const pot = await lottery.methods.getBalance();

    assert(difference > web3.utils.toWei('1.8', 'ether'));
    assert.equal(0, players.length);
    assert.equal(0, pot);
  });
```

When I deploy the smart contract to the remix - ethereum IDE getBalance returns the balance of the pot as wanted but when I run npm run test locally then I get an assertion error:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 0 == {
  _ethAccounts: <ref *7> Accounts {
    _ethereumCall: {
      getChainId: [Function: send] {
        call: 'eth_chainId',
        method: Method {
          abiCoder: undefined,
          accounts: undefined,
          call: 'eth_chainId',
          defaultAccount: null,
          defaultBlock: 'latest',
          defaultChain: undefined,
          defaultCommon: undefined,
          defaultHardfork: undefined,
          extraFormatters: undefined,
          handleRevert: undefined,
          inputFor...
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/Lottery.test.js:101:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

How can I fix this?
p.s. this contract is for learning purposes I know that the randomness is not very robust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling contract read-only methods with `web3js`, you need to use the `.call()` function.

```
const pot = await lottery.methods.getBalance().call()`; // added `.call()`
```

instead of

```
const pot = await lottery.methods.getBalance(); // original code
```

Docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is just to test the balance, use `web3.eth.getBalance` instead of defining the `getBalance` inside the contract.

```
const contractBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(lottery.options.address);
```